# how do I assertTextPresent in a table in an iframe?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I've got a chunk of text in an iframe and I'd like to assert that the text is correct. However, it always fails, even after selecting the iframe.

```
<iframe>
...               
    <tbody>
            <tr class="sub">
                <td width="100%" class="bodyText">Your username has been sent to: f*****@example.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>                                       
    </tbody>
 </iframe>
```

The selenium script looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>index=0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>has been sent</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Select frame always passes. There is only one frame on the page. AssertTextPresent always fails. I've read a related bug report on the Selenium JIRA -- from 2 years ago with no responses. Looked around on the web a bit and the suggestion is to select the frame then assert, which is what I'm doing. Stumped.

What should I do to check for text that is in an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer 2 minutes later. I forgot that sometimes with selenium IDE you use the Target field and sometimes you use the Value field. In this case, putting `has been sent` into the value field did the trick.